# Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Show that $f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Show that $f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous we have that $|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1.$

Now if $(a,b)$ is partitioned such that $a=x_0 < x_1 < \dots <x_{n-1} <x_n =b$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i})|$ e.g the sum length of the $n$ partitions of the graph $f$ is less than or equal to the length of the difference of the end points.

But now from uniform continuity if each $|f(x_{i-1})-f(x_i)| < 1$, then $$|f(x)-f(y)| < \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i})| < n \varepsilon = n$$ which would conclude the boundedness. I'm confused since the solution my classmate had was something of the following.

He had the same argument slightly modified that Since $f$ is uniformly continuous we have that $|x-y| < 2\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1.$ Then he picked $p$ to be the midpoint of $(a,b)$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p+m\delta \ge b$. Considering the intervals $$(a,p-(m-1)\delta], [p-(m-1)\delta,p-(m-2)\delta], \dots, [p+(m-1)\delta,b)$$ and concluded that $$|f(x)-f(p)|\le |f(x)-f(p+(j-1)\delta|+\dots + |f(p+\delta)-f(p)| = 1 + \dots+1 = j \le m$$

I'm very confused about what's the point of considering the midpoint of $(a,b)$ and what even is $p+m\delta$ or the intervals $(a,p-(m-1)\delta], [p-(m-1)\delta,p-(m-2)\delta], \dots, [p+(m-1)\delta,b)$ representing here? Is there something fundamental I'm missing from my part of the proof?

Comment: One thing that seems problematic is that you're evaluating $f(x_0) = f(a)$, but $f$ isn't defined at $a$. Similarly for $b$.

Comment: I think it suffices to break $(a,b)$ into three subintervals as follows. Choose $\delta > 0$ small enough that $|f(x) - f(y)| < 1$ for all $|x-y| < \delta$, and also small enough so that $a+\delta < b - \delta$. Then $(a,b)$ is the disjoint union of $(a, a+\delta)$, $[a+\delta, b - \delta]$, and $(b - \delta, b)$. Then $f$ is bounded on the middle interval because that interval is compact, and it's bounded on the first and third intervals by an argument similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is unbounded, find an increasing sequence $(|f(x_n)|) \to \infty$. Let $\delta > 0$ and cover $(a,b)$ by finitely many $\delta$-balls; one contains infinitely many $x_n$, so $f$ is unbounded here. Hence $f$ is not uniformly continuous.